# Time Series Analysis from start

Tags: time, series

I have a table with 4500 records, it has two columns, one is a date and the other column just as a 1 in each row next to the data.

I am looking to try and do a simple time series analysis to look at the numbers over a period of time and if I can forecast any data using this table.

| Date | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 1 |
| 02/02/2022 | 1 |

the table looks like this and I wanted to do a timeseries over a couple of years counting a 1 for each date if that makes sense.

what would the script be in r to load the data from a csv called Data and then do a time series that has the date on one axis and a line plotting along it.

thanks

I couldnt load any data and wasnt sure what to do with it.